# Why 'Q' for the 'Q Continuum'?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q

Is there a particular reason why it is the **Q** Continuum? Any idea who came up with the character/race and why s/he chose this letter?

[From Memory-Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Q_Continuum#Apocrypha)'s "Apocrypha":

> In *The Eternal Tide*, it is revealed that the Q Continuum manifested as a creative force to 'oppose' the destructive potential of the **Omega Continuum** after it was disrupted and the decay of the universe accelerated.

[Ϙ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qoppa) vs. [ω](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega)?

Comment: You would think that if it was opposed to something called Omega they would have gone with "Alpha"

Comment: Because Q is better than P, and R is too "pirate".

Comment: @Monty129 "Q" came _waay_ first, though

Comment: The name "Q" was chosen by Gene Roddenberry, in honor of an English Star Trek fan, Janet Quarton. She was the first president of the UK Star Trek fan club, and Gene Roddenberry and many others spent time at her home, in the Scottish highlands.   - this is from the linked [pre-duplicate answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18942/why-are-all-the-q-named-q).